# How to escape multiple quotes and commas within quotes?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, sed

How do I properly escape multiple quotes and commas with awk, to separate csv fields that are enclosed by quotes? The following example should make it more clear:

Have:

```
mike,3
"first, second",6 
"height 6""7""", good","4, 5"
```

Want (desired separation marked by []):

```
[mike] [3]
["first, second"] [6] 
["height 6""7""", good"] ["4, 5"]
```

Tried [GNU awk with the FPAT variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) without luck:

```
gawk -vFPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{print $1}' my_file.csv
mike
"first, second"
"height 6""7""" # note the missing ", good"
```

Excel and/or LibraOffice can parse this csv correctly without hiccup. There must be a way to parse it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Use proper CSV parsers from PHP/python not awk

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I should add some context. This is part of a data pipeline on a few GB data (output of a Mapreduce job), I'd like to do more stream editing to shrink the data down to manageable size to feed into python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work...

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"|"([^"]*""+[^"]*)+"' ...
```

however, I think multiple quotes need to be collapsed.

In action

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]+|"[^"]+"|"([^"]*""+[^"]*)+"' -v OFS='> <' '{print "<"$1,$2">"}' file

<mike> <3>
<"first, second"> <6>
<"height 6""7""", good"> <"4, 5">
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the original problem, but not the updated one (where second field can be quoted, too). My bad for not giving a representative example.

Comment: I don't see a difference.  What did you get?

Comment: hmm I couldn't replicate what I thought was problematic. Must be dreaming earlier.  The solution parsed my file nicely. Thanks! As for collapsing the quotes, it's not a problem in my case, since I'm going to parse it in Python or R after awk processing and they can handle it.